# How can I move a commit to the staging area when only one commit exists?

Tags: git, git-reset

I have a Git repository where only one commit lives. I'd like to move this commit to staging area. the known command is `git reset --soft`. So I typed something like that:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
$ git log
commit 2d70c0de8824967378da348afa7be6eca9839dcc
Author: gtchoi <gtchoi@nhnent.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 8 18:54:25 2015 +0900
    the first commit.
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
$ git reset --soft 2d70c0de8824967378da348afa7be6eca9839dcc
$ git log
commit 2d70c0de8824967378da348afa7be6eca9839dcc
Author: gtchoi <gtchoi@nhnent.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 8 18:54:25 2015 +0900

    the first commit.
```

the argument `HEAD~1` and `HEAD^` causes a fatal error and I have no result when typing `git reset <SHA-1 of commit>` and the first commit won't be deleted. What's wrong with this? Is this bug?

Comment: I respect your career as a Git surgeon. Here is my git repository: https://github.com/gtchoi/guestbook_2015. you may try this

Comment: If theres only one commit and you want to reset it. Why not just create a new repo with the content? Just drop the `.git` directory and do `git init` again

Comment: As per my understandin what you are asking is not possible, treating git repo as a timeline, you are trying go back in time which doesnt exist. Just create new timeline.

Comment: `git reset HEAD~1` will work but more to the point, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? are you trying to rewrite the commit history?

Answer (score 0):

In Git, the **HEAD** is a reference to the latest commit(a pointer to the recently checkout out commit object). So in your case, **HEAD** refers to your one and only commit.

By Git's syntax, **HEAD^(or HEAD~1)** refers to the commit object which is the second last commit done in the current branch. In your case, this is not at all present. Hence the error is expected, and not a bug.

Now, coming to your issue, let's see how we can rescue the situation:

> git reset --soft

This will just reset HEAD pointer. This won't delete the commit, nor will it break the connection between the branch and the commit object.

Instead of deleting, you could revert the commit by running:

> git revert

As expected, this will only add another commit reverting the changes. Most probably this is not what you want.

The simple(and clean) way of doing what you want is:

Make any changes in your project directory that you may have missed out in the first commit. Then add all those changes to staging area.

> git add --all

And run:

> git commit --amend -m "the first commit"

Not you have replaced that commit object in the history. See by running:

> git log --oneline